# Azure Data Factory Simple Data Flow Failed

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a simple data flow that copies one table to another in an azure sql database,

all Linked services and Datasets have been created fine, But when i run my dataflow within a pipeline, i just get a status of Failed.

[Image of Pipeline with failed dataflow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yZiA.png)

There there any common mistakes that make this happen, also is there a more detailed error log somewhere in the portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out the error and correct the issue.  I was trying to insert into a primary key, Identity Insert error. So i just unmapped that primary key column.

All sorted!